# Macros for Debug and Release modes

Tags: c++

could anyone explain to me why is DEBUG MACROs is prefered than the WRITE option???
could you also show mw an full example on COMPILING FOR DEBUGGING. (DEBUG MACROS)?
How could DEBUG MACROS debug our programs?

Comment: Where did you see a DEBUG macro? Do you have an example? Also, what is WRITE option?

Comment: I mean by WRITE that we use printf or cout to check the values of our variables in order to avoid the bugs.

Comment: I don't think you can say that a DEBUG macro is preferable to using `printf()` because they are often used together.

Comment: here is an example:  #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main(){int x=0,y=0; int d=x/y; cout d; //here is a bug : trying to divide by 0 so to solve it with write we just print the values before operation and we will find that y is 0*/  }

Comment: In your example, a DEBUG macro can be used to tell the compiler to conditionally compile the statements to print the values. This means that you cannot say that a DEBUG macro is preferred over printing values because you can use them together.

Comment: Here is a question that shows how you can use macros for debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135069/ifdef-vs-if-which-is-better-safer-as-a-method-for-enabling-disabling-compila

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug macros don't "debug programs", but they provide the ability to debug the program.

It can be extra checks.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define CHECK_NON_ZERO(x)  if (x == 0) cout << "Error, should be zero!\n"; 
#else
#define CHECK_NON_ZERO(x)
#endif

float func(int x)
{  
   CHECK_NON_ZERO(x);

   return 1.0f/x; 
}
```

Obviously, once you have done your testing of the code, in a release build, you probably don't want to have the extra checks that `x` is non-zero, so you don't have the extra check.

Comment: ok I got it. but why did you write #ifdef DEBUG?? do you mean DEBUG mode?? or any word instead DEBUG you could use????

Comment: I mean in debug build - but different environments have different ways of saying "debug build", and you could of course have your own `#ifdef MY_DEBUG`, and use `-DMY_DEBUG` as an option to the compiler when you want to enable this. That is not the point of my post tho' - the point is that SOMETIMES you have code that only make sense when you are developing the software. Clearly, calling this function with zero would cause a bad result, so it's good to check for it. But "good code" should not call this function with zero in the first place, so it's not required to test for it in release.

Comment: I called this function with zero but it didn't prints the error you wrote.

Comment: in addition when I tried to edit the word DEBUG to _DEBUG I got 2 compile-time errors: cout undeclared identifier. 2: << illegal right operand

Comment: Yes, obviously, if you haven't included `<iostream>` in your code, and you may need `std::` in front. It's meant to be a simple example.

Comment: ok. I got it. it's genius. I do apreciate your help Mats on my endless questions. at last could you explain why it is not required to for it in RELEASE?

Comment: Well, if you want it in release, then you wouldn't put it in a macro - the point is that if you have a lot of places that you have code similar to this to check consistency and catch bad programming, you hopefully don't need that when the code is ready for release, because you have tested it and know that it works in every aspect. So you want to remove "check consistency" in 2341 places in the code all at once. That's a lot of code to change (and of course, you risk breaking the code by accidentally remove a line too many, or something like that). A macro is just one place to edit.

Comment: ok. so you mean we have to build our code in debug build and when it works ok we rebuild it in RELEASE?

Comment: Yes. Of course, before you distribute the release you need to thoroughly test it again, because there can be things that appear to work in a debug build that stop working due to optimisation in a release build - especially if the code is "using" things that aren't clearly defined in the language.

Comment: ok. thank you too much. at last one more question: how could I build it in RELEASE mode??

Comment: You select `RELEASE` instead of `DEBUG` in the build configuration (or something like that - I haven't used Visual Studio for a couple of years now)

Comment: ok. Mats thank you again for your help that figured it out

Answer (score 1):

There is the good old assert(...). Being a noop if NDEBUG is defined, but a check if NDEBUG is not defined.

By the way: Debug macros do not debug, just log information.