# Efficient way of generalizing a C++ code (a 2D computation to 3D computation)

Tags: c++, macros

I am writing a `C++` code which does 2D and 3D computations. The main function has an argument from which I can tell whether to do 2D or 3D computation (`dim=2` or `dim=3`). What would be the best option to enabling/disabling compilation of particular sections of code based on `dim`? I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135454/1227860) which suggest to use *`#ifdef`*, so I was thinking of defining a macro then use *`#ifdef`*:

```
if( dim == 2 )
    #define DISABLE_3D true
```

I am sure there is a better way of doing this and I would love to have that.

Comment: You cannot mix macros and code in that way. If the dim value is known at compile-time per function call, you could make it a template parameter. The compiler can easily optimize out unused code paths based on constant values. To be honest, unless profiling has shown this is a bottleneck, I would just pass dim as a normal parameter. Checking the value of an int is not a costly operation..

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to identify whether they are compile-time or run-time dependent.  `#ifdef` macros are compile-time dependent so the program will be built with either just 2D or 3D capability.  If you need to have a function that works for both 2D and 3D computations during run-time, you should avoid `#ifdef` macros.

Instead of using `if (dim==2)` decision, you might utilize 'function overriding' feature of C++.
Since there are many details missing, I cannot give a specific example but if there are differences in 2D and 3D data, it could be a hint that function overriding can be implemented.

Comment: If true, you should avoid `#ifdef` macros.