# Computed Includes in C

Tags: c, macros, header-files

I was reading the C Preprocessor guide page on gnu.org on computed includes which has the following explanation:

> 2.6 Computed Includes
>
> Sometimes it is necessary to select one of several different header
>   files to be included into your program. They might specify
>   configuration parameters to be used on different sorts of operating
>   systems, for instance. You could do this with a series of
>   conditionals,

```
#if SYSTEM_1
# include "system_1.h"
#elif SYSTEM_2
# include "system_2.h"
#elif SYSTEM_3 …
#endif
```

> That rapidly becomes tedious. Instead, the preprocessor offers the
>   ability to use a macro for the header name. This is called a computed
>   include. Instead of writing a header name as the direct argument of
>   ‘#include’, you simply put a macro name there instead:

```
#define SYSTEM_H "system_1.h" 
…
#include SYSTEM_H
```

This doesn't make sense to me. The first code snippet allows for optionality based on which system type you encounter by using branching if elifs. The second seems to have no optionality as a macro is used to define a particular system type and then the macro is placed into the include statement without any code that would imply its definition can be changed. Yet, the text implies these are equivalent and that the second is a shorthand for the first. Can anyone explain how the optionality of the first code snippet exists in the second? I also don't know what code is implied to be contained in the "..." in the second code snippet.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with "C" (or C++) per se: it's entirely CPP (the [C Preprocessor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm)). This link might better help understanding particular use cases: [#ifdef vs #if - which is better/safer as a method for enabling/disabling compilation of particular sections of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135069)  SHORT ANSWER:   It's all macro evaluation/macro substitution.  Both CPP expressions ultimately write the same text values into the source file.

Comment: @paulsm You first sentence is misleading at best, and downright wrong at worst. The C preprocessor is part of the C language specification (see ISO 9989), so this has anything to do with C.

Comment: ... and the C preprocessor part of the compiler needs to behave *as if*. It doesn't mean that the system has a separate preprocessed file, or that there would need to be a separate preprocessor, or even a preprocessing *stage*.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there *IS* a separate preprocessed file (it's called "the source file"), a separate POSTprocessed "file", and most definely a "preprocessing stage".  And as far as I'm concerned, "C" != "ISO C standard".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some other places in the code or build system that define or don't define the macros that are being tested in the conditionals. What's suggested is that instead of those places defining lots of different `SYSTEM_1`, `SYSTEM_2`, etc. macros, they'll just define `SYSTEM_H` to the value that's desired.

Most likely this won't actually be in an explicit `#define`, instead of will be in a compiler option, e.g.

```
gcc -DSYSTEM_H='"system_1.h"' ...
```

And this will most likely actually come from a setting in a makefile or other configuration file.

Comment: Thank you - that's the key point I *DIDN'T* mention in my comments above.  That the REAL value of "computed includes" comes from using a `-D` macro definition EXTERNALLY (e.g. from a "makefile").

Comment: That clears things up! One follow up question: Does using a macro like that allow you to include multiple .h files? So, in this example, would SYSTEM_H allow you to include system_1.h and system_2.h etc. or would the SYSTEM_H be defined once in some other place and then only that will be included?

Comment: Each macro could only be used to include one file, there's no way to loop over macro values. You'd need multiple macros like `SYSTEM_H`, `CPUTYPE_H`, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't that introduce a difference between the first code snippet and second snippet though? The first code snippet uses elif so you could hypothetically include all the system.h files. But if the macro can't be looped over or used to include multiple .h files wouldn't you need a macro for every individual .h file you wanted to include thus making it just as verbose as the first option?

Comment: Since the first code snippet uses `#elif`, only the first match is executed, so all the options are mutually exclusive and just one file is included. What you're thinking of would be true if it used a series of separate `#if`.